# How to migrate mdadm RAID10 with 4 disks to RAID5?

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm, raid-5, raid-10

I have a software RAID10 based on Linux’ mdadm under Debian Buster. Originally I found RAID10 had best performance. But I need more space and accept to trade some write performance for +50% space.

```
# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid10] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4]
md1 : active raid10 sdd1[5] sda1[4] sdb1[1] sdc1[2]
      3899738112 blocks super 1.2 512K chunks 2 near-copies [4/4] [UUUU]
      bitmap: 3/30 pages [12KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

This storage is served via NFS and ideally the RAID could be transformed without downtime. Yes, I have backups and a failure wouldn’t be critical but why not migrate without disruption if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I found an article from 2012 describing the process. The commands turned out to be quite right. Back then the author had problems that the `mdadm` utility (or probably the kernel driver) immediately hung the system with the first command. This issue seems to have been fixed since then.

https://www.tummy.com/blogs/2012/03/29/changing-a-raid-10-into-a-raid-5/

There is no direct path from RAID10→RAID5 in mdadm. Instead you have to first degrade it RAID0:

```
# mdadm --grow /dev/md1 --level=0 --raid-devices=2
mdadm: /dev/md1: could not set level to raid0
```

This was instantly effective and made 2 devices fail and be removed from the array. Unfortunately the RAID level wasn’t set to RAID0. `dmesg` showed:

```
md/raid0:md1: All mirrors must be already degraded!
md: md1: raid0 would not accept array
```

I found the issue was that `sysfs` reported the array as *not* being degraded although it actually was and `mdadm` and `cat /proc/mdstat` showed correctly:

```
# cat /sys/block/md1/md/degraded
0
```

I found no other way to fix this as to stop the NFS server, unmount the filesystem, close the LUKS device, stop the RAID array, re-assemble the RAID array and restart all services. Afterwards it was correctly reported as degraded and could be transformed into RAID0.

Then I could grow it back to 4 devices with RAID5:

```
# mdadm --grow /dev/md1 --level=5 --raid-devices=5 --add /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdd1
```

Unlike ever before `cat /proc/mdstat` didn’t show a “rebuild” in progress but a “reshape”. This took quite a while (around 10 hours) and the system responded much slower than during RAID10 rebuilds. I left it alone for the rebuild time.

Since reshape has completed the RAID5 is clean and speed is good. I probably made mistakes when measuring but read speed is now faster than what I recorded before and write speed is also acceptable for me.

```
# cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid10] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md1 : active raid5 sdd1[5] sdb1[3] sda1[4] sdc1[7]
      5849607168 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]

unused devices: <none>
```

(disclaimer: The whole story was written down when the migration was already completed. I tried carefully to describe the actual commands and errors messages but there may be minor mistakes. The overall process worked like described.)

Answer (score 0):

Not (yet) tested (don't trust important data to the steps below) but here an idea for any scenario where the usable space is increased and `mdadm --grow` says "RAID10 layout too complex for Grow operation":

1. Stop the md
2. Backup the first few MiB of each partition of the md (assuming the RAID superblocks are near the start of each partition)
3. Wipe the superblocks
4. Create a RAID5 (or other RAID) with `--assume-clean` using the partitions
5. Create snapshots of each partition of the md, e.g. follow https://gist.github.com/jowagner/b36024636140ddf453c12eaf6e590b5d
6. Restore the backup of the partitions from step 2 into snapshots of the partitions
7. Assemble the RAID10 from the snapshots
8. `dd` all data from the RAID10 to the RAID5. Using the least common multiple of the 2 stripe sizes is probably best for performance but any blocksize should do. The first few reads will not be corrupted by the writes because they come from copy-on-write data written in step 5. The remaining reads will not be corrupted as they are ahead with a safe distant from the writes on each partition (hence the limitation of this idea to scenarios where the the usable space is increased).
9. Stop the RAID10
10. Discard the snapshots

This assumes that a snapshot only redirect writes to the snapshots to a COW device and that writes to the origin device do not trigger a copy of the old data to be stored in the COW device (otherwise the solution would not be practical as too much extra space is needed).

Furthermore, if the superblocks of the old RAID are near the end of each partition these data also need to be backed up before step 3. Calculate a suitable position to seek to and the data amount. I'd use a few lines of Python but there probably is a command line tool that can do it.